# call specific pubsub topic based on condition in apache beam with python

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like read topics from pubsub topic1 and write cleaned json to topic2 and topic3 based on the condition.

let say: i have a flag in the json comes from topic1, i do some transformations, and check the flag value and write to topic2 and topic3 based on the flag value.

i have tried the below but from here i am not able to move further, since no idea how to call call the pipe based on the condition.

my Beam pipe code as below:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    Ingest = ( p
                | 'Read from Topic' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.topic).with_output_types(bytes)
                | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(decode_message)
                | 'Make One Json' >> beam.Map(make_one)
                | 'Split based on event' >> beam.Map(split)
                # when event_name== 'aa_afo_addtocart_clicked'
                | 'write to topic2'
                # when event_name== 'aa_afo_merchantpage_visited'
                | 'write to topic3'

            )
```

4th step i am calling the split function, but pls guide me how to write the splited output to multiple topics.

the split python function do the following.
gets the one single input json -> check the flag and split the result as two -> one should go topic2 and another one should go to topic3.

```
def split(p):
    json_obj_list = json.load(p)
    jb =[]
    for json_obj in json_obj_list:
       if json_obj['event_name']== 'aa_afo_addtocart_clicked':
          filename = json_obj['event_name'] + '.json'
          with open(filename, 'a') as out_json_file:
            json_string = json.dumps(json_obj)
            print(json_string)
            #json.dump(json_obj, out_json_file)
       if json_obj['event_name'] == 'aa_afo_merchantpage_visited':
          filename = json_obj['event_name'] + '.json'
          with open(filename, 'a') as out_json_file:
            json_string = json.dumps(json_obj)
            print(json_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to create several output as described in the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs). Like that, you perform your split and you have 2 PCollections as output.

Then process independently the 2 PCollections: sink in topic 2 and topic 3.